# Manipulate all Buttons on a Layout

Tags: java, android

I have a layout (FullBody) that have some other layouts inside(Header, footer), and each layout have a group of buttons and other ellements(including other layouts). How can i manipulate all buttons with a for() or other thing?

I've tried this( [Easy way to setOnClickListener() on all Activity Buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7048470/easy-way-to-setonclicklistener-on-all-activity-buttons) ):

```
ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.myrootlayout);
View v;
for(int i = 0; i < group.getChildCount(); i++) {
v = group.getChildAt(i);
if(v instanceof Button) v.setOnClickListener(this)
}
```

This only selects the first level childs of the layout. How can i access all levels(Like DFS ) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To go over all levels of your layout you'll need to apply recursion:

```
ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.myrootlayout);
setListenerForGroup(group);
```

Where:

```
void setListenerForGroup(ViewGroup group) {
   int count = group.getChildCount(); <------- more efficient
   for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
       View v = group.getChildAt(i);
       if (v instanceof Button)
           v.setOnClickListener(this);
       else if (v instanceof ViewGroup)
           setListenerForGroup((ViewGroup)v);
   }
}
```